# Sass is just crashing over and over with incorrect error message

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I've seen this pop up now and again, and normally just re-typing my definitions make it leave me alone, but this time Sass is really set on crashing.

It's alternating between this error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...a(0,0,0,0.4); }": expected "}", was "{"
    on line 13 of src/styles/_components/_wysiwyg.sass
    from line 20 of src/styles/app.sass
```

and the classic:
`Only properties maybe nested beneath properties)`

Problem is, both times the Sass is completely perfect. It's like it's seeing some invisible characters or something:

```
.wysiwyg-wrapper
margin-bottom: 100px

.rdw-editor-toolbar
    background: transparent
    border: none
    margin: 0px
    padding: 5px 0px
    font-size: 14px

    .rdw-link-modal
        background: $bg3
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)

    &>div
        margin-bottom: 0px
```

With the above, it somehow gets the 'background' term stuck and compiles it into the next, so in my inspector, `rdw-link-modal` has:

`background: #303539`

`background-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)`

Is this something anyone's seen before? IT's driving me totally insane.

Comment: You have a double indentation on line 17, none on line 2.

Comment: The indentation on line 2 was a bit of a red herring - I think that came from pasting into SO. I don't see any double indentation on line 17, though.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, I got there in the end.

VS Code was using 4 spaces for indentation, while on previous occasions it was using tabs.

Weird, but I guess Sass isn't at fault here.